# Implement Multilingual Site Pages in Salesforce Communities using Lightning Web Components

Tags: community, lightning-web-components

I am trying to implement multilingual community pages using Lightning Web Components, hence I have used translation workbench, custom labels, user language preference  and imported them to my LWC.
Here when the lwc is added to communities, the language translation is not happening and is showing in English for end users [whose preferred language is french]...it's working fine for admins [because admins has language toggling option given in communities].
Below image is from Admin log in

[image]

Where as if we add the same LWC in home page or record page...language translations is working as expected based on Users language preferance...
Any views on how to achieve this in Salesforce communities using LWC?

Answer (score 0):

- Add Option to change the language i.e combobox or dropdown at corner in your community
- On change of that option based on selected language you need to append language param to your Url i.e
  https://{my.site.com}/s/?***language=en_US***